# Shift in 2Dimage when converting from lidar point cloud to 2d Image

Tags: python, point-clouds, lidar

I am mapping a lidar point cloud to 2d image. I have successfully mapped the point cloud to 2d image but there is a shift of 0.5 meter to 1meter in the 2d image from the lidar point cloud when overlaped. This overlapping is important for me as i will work with polygon which is created by the lidar data, The polygon and the image also doesnot overlap properly. The extent of the 2d image is of the lidar data. I cannot figure it out why there is a small misalignment even though they are in the same coordinate system and the image have the same extent as the lidar data.

Here is the data i am working on.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cBNDJmoh8i3Sb4AoU5FLDqPXjy7OYfaW?usp=sharing

Here is the code that i have tired.

```
import laspy
import rasterio
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import geopandas as gpd
class SingleTree:
    def __init__(self, las_data):
        self.points = np.vstack((las_data.x, las_data.y, las_data.z, las_data.red, las_data.green, 
                                 las_data.blue)).T

        
    def point_cloud_to_image(self, output_size):
        
        # Extract x, y, and color values
        x = self.points[:, 0]
        y = self.points[:, 1]
        red = self.points[:, 3]
        green = self.points[:, 4]
        blue = self.points[:, 5]
        
        # Normalize coordinates to range [0, 1]
        x_normalized = (x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min())
        y_normalized = (y - y.min()) / (y.max() - y.min())
        
        # Scale normalized coordinates to image size, ensuring they are within the bounds
        x_img = np.clip((x_normalized * (output_size[1] - 1)).astype(int), 0, output_size[1] - 1)
        y_img = np.clip((y_normalized * (output_size[0] - 1)).astype(int), 0, output_size[0] - 1)

        # Convert color values to 8-bit
        r = np.interp(red, (red.min(), red.max()), (0, 255)).astype(np.uint8)
        g = np.interp(green, (green.min(), green.max()), (0, 255)).astype(np.uint8)
        b = np.interp(blue, (blue.min(), blue.max()), (0, 255)).astype(np.uint8)

        # Initialize an empty image
        img = np.zeros(output_size + (3,), dtype=np.uint8)
        
        
        # Assign colors to image pixels safely
        for xi, yi, ri, gi, bi in zip(x_img, y_img, r, g, b):
            img[yi, xi] = [ri, gi, bi]
        
        return img

    def polygon_bound(self, poly_path):
        # Load the polygon data
        gdf = gpd.read_file(poly_path)

        # Assuming you're interested in the first polygon if there are multiple
        polygon = gdf.geometry[0]

        # Get the bounding box of the polygon
        minx, miny, maxx, maxy = polygon.bounds
        
        polygon_width = maxx - minx
        polygon_height = maxy - miny

        # The top-left corner coordinates
        top_left_x = minx
        top_left_y = miny
        
        return top_left_x, top_left_y, polygon_width, polygon_height

import os
from rasterio.transform import from_origin
# Assuming 'path' is the directory containing your '.las' files
path = r"lasdata path"
output_path = r"path"
number_of_files = len([name for name in os.listdir("directory of lasdata")])
discarded_lasdata = []
# Loop through your LAS files
for i in range(1, number_of_files):
    file = f"tree_i{i}.las"
    poly_file = "polygons\\poly{}.shp".format(i)
    image_path = os.path.join(path, file)
    
    # Read the LAS file
    las_data = laspy.read(image_path)
    
    # Process the point cloud to generate an image
    tree = SingleTree(las_data)
    
    top_left_x, top_left_y, polygon_width, polygon_height = tree.polygon_bound(poly_file)
    # Get metadata from LAS file for georeferencing
    scale = las_data.header.scale
    offset = las_data.header.offset
    
    # Assuming las_data is a LasData object from laspy
    min_x, min_y, min_z = las_data.header.min
    max_x, max_y, max_z = las_data.header.max
    
    lidar_width = round((max_x - min_x), 0)
    lidar_height = round((max_y - min_y), 0)
    
    if (lidar_width <= 0 or lidar_height <= 0):
        discarded_lasdata.append(i)
        continue
        
    ltop_left_x = min_x
    ltop_left_y = min_y
    
    resolution = 0.5
    
    image_width_pixels = int((lidar_width * 2 + 5) / resolution)
    image_height_pixels = int((lidar_height * 2 + 5) / resolution)
    
    img = tree.point_cloud_to_image((int(lidar_height*2), int(lidar_width*2)))
    
    # Create the geotransform
    transform = from_origin(ltop_left_x, ltop_left_y, resolution, -resolution)
    
    # Define the CRS (coordinate reference system)
    crs = "EPSG:25832"  # Replace with the correct EPSG code for your data
    
    # Define the rasterio metadata dictionary
    meta = {
        'driver': 'GTiff',
        'dtype': 'uint8',
        'nodata': None,
        'width': img.shape[1],
        'height': img.shape[0],
        'count': 3,
        'crs': crs,
        'transform': transform,
        'compress': 'lzw'
    }
    
    output_filename = os.path.join(output_path, f"lidar_test{i}.tif")
    
    # Write the image data and metadata to a GeoTIFF
    with rasterio.open(output_filename, 'w', **meta) as dst:
        for k in range(img.shape[2]):
            dst.write(img[:, :, k], k+1)

print("GeoTIFFs have been saved.")
```

You can see that the polygon doesnot properly overlap with image whereas all the lidar point fall inside the polygon
[image: polygon overlapped with image]
[image: lidar data overlapped with polygon]

Edit: Upon second look i found that the extent of the lidar data and image is not same and is off by 0 to 1 meter. I think this is because the lidar data width and height is in floating point and we pass an integer as the width and height.But i cannot still figure the solution

Comment: Could you share also the data to reproduce your example? Or a synthetic toy example to test your code with?

Comment: @Luca i have added the data in the question

Comment: Could you please also add the code to get the images you have posted? I did not have the time to work a lot about it, but it looks like the code you posted just saves the tiff image without any superimposed boundary. Thank you!

Comment: @Luca I use a software called qgis to display the images and polygons and i took a snippet of it

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your problem could come from the lines

```
x_img = np.clip((x_normalized * (output_size[1] - 1)).astype(int), 0, output_size[1] - 1)
y_img = np.clip((y_normalized * (output_size[0] - 1)).astype(int), 0, output_size[0] - 1)
```

as `astype` just removes decimals, instead of rounding to the closer integer. This is coherent with the fact that your image is shifted to the left.

You can try to round before typecasting, e.g. with

```
x_img = np.clip(np.round((x_normalized * (output_size[1]))), 0, output_size[1]-1).astype(int)
y_img = np.clip(np.round((y_normalized * (output_size[0]))), 0, output_size[0]-1).astype(int)
```

Comment: I tried this but doesnot work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the bounding box information from the lidar data instead of the minimum values to ensures that the coordinates are normalized relative to the lidar data:

```
x_normalized = (x - ltop_left_x) / (resolution * output_size[1])
y_normalized = 1 - (y - ltop_left_y) / (resolution * output_size[0])
```

The calculation of image width and height has to be adjusted to use the bounding box dimensions from the polygon instead of the lidar data:

```
image_width_pixels = int((polygon_width + 5) / resolution)
image_height_pixels = int((polygon_height + 5) / resolution)
```

Create geotransform using the top_left_x and top_left_y values obtained from the polygon bounding box to ensure proper GeoTIFF reference.

```
transform = from_origin(top_left_x, top_left_y, resolution, -resolution)
```